# Match if string contains another

Tags: excel, vba

I want to consider these two strings for example equal: `leve mur#1` and `leve mur`

I found `Like` and `InStr` but I'm not interested in the position. I just want to ignore what's after the hashtag.

```vb
Dim oHead As Long
oHead = wF.Match(LookingHead.Value, _
          Range("A1", Cells(1, _
          Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column)), False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use:

```
if instr(1 str1, str2, vbTextCompare) > 0 then
    'str2 has been found in str1
end if
```

Using the same approach, if you want to ignore what is after the hashtag...

```
hashPosit = InStr(1, str1, "#", vbTextCompare)
if hashPosit > 0 then
    'We have a hash in this string, only take to the left
    subStr1 = left(str1,hashPosit)
else 
    'No hash exists, take all string
    subStr1 = str1
endif

if instr(1, subStr1, str2, vbTextCompare) > 0 then
    'str2 has been found in the portion of str1 to the left of the #
end if
```

Bit clunky I suppose, but you could fire it into a function and it'd be clean enough.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you don't want to use `Instr` but that is what I would think of first to solve this particular problem. When I use `Instr` I never really care about where in the string the match was found. I just need to know if one string contains the other.
In your case, you may have a smaller string and a larger string. The order might not be known at run time, so, just run `Instr` both ways to make sure you catch any case.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
   Dim Str1 As String
   Dim Str2 As String

   Str1 = "leve mur#1"
   Str2 = "leve mur"

   If Contains(Str1, Str2) Then
       MsgBox "They match"
   Else
       MsgBox "No match"
   End If
End Sub

Function Contains(Str1 As String, Str2 As String) As Boolean

   If Instr(Str1, Str2) > 0 Or Instr(Str2, Str1) > 0 Then
      Contains = True
   Else
      Contains = False
   End If

End Function
```

Comment: cuz i loop through an entire column looking for matches in another so i can have stuff like this :       leve mur#1 leve mur #2 etc compared to leve mur or test#1 test#2 etc compared to test